# Increase the chances of a record being selected in a random select

Tags: php, mysql, random

When using `ORDER BY RAND()` how can you go about giving more "weight" to some records over others so the chances of them being selected increase?

Answer (score 3):

I found [an extensive article on the problem](http://use.perl.org/~bart/journal/33630) which provides an ordering solution. I'm very, very, far from mastering probability, statistics, or any sort of math, but based on my own testing it seems pretty solid. It uses the same idea of a "selection weight" column.. just make sure the default and all values for this column are nonzero.

```
WHERE selection_weight > 0 ... ORDER BY ( -LOG(1.0 - RAND()) / selection_weight )
```

Using the [better random-selection query](http://www.paperplanes.de/2008/4/24/mysql_nonos_order_by_rand.html) that Mike posted, you could try something like:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM ( SELECT id
       FROM users
       WHERE selection_weight > 0
       ORDER BY ( -LOG(1.0 - RAND()) / selection_weight ) ) AS random_users
JOIN users ON random_users.id = users.id
```

This query ran in 10 - 20 ms on a 2,000-record table I was using for testing. I hope this helps!

---

#### Original answer

If you have an integer column in the table that corresponds to the selection weight:

```
ORDER BY RAND() * selection_weight DESC
```

This will probably be very slow, however.. I'll keep looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this why MySQL, however if the data set isn't too large, you could add a column called "weight" and then return the whole thing into an array. Then using php, loop through the array and add "weight" number of entries to another array and then randomly select an entry from the second array. This seems really sloppy to me for some reason though.

Comment: Also, read this: http://www.paperplanes.de/2008/4/24/mysql_nonos_order_by_rand.html